# Dynamic child component under Parent component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a component where there is only a text field with some logic. Now I would like to use this component as a child component in another Parent component. Now I have three questions:

1. How can I add the child component under the form group of the parent component
2. How can I add the required validator whenever needed in any parent component.
3. If the child component is used multiple times in a parent component how can I set the name field dynamically?

Comment: you can just pass it the form group directly via an input binding - the validators work the same because its part of the parent form group.  it doesn't care that the child is used multiple times - you can create a name field via an array

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want your component to implement the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface - this allows you to bind your component to either `ngModel` in template driven forms, or `formControl` (or `formControlName`) in reactive forms to be part of the form directly, and correctly react to changes in the form.

To also handle validators, your component will also have to implement [Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator) interface.

There are multiple comprehensive guides on how to correctly implement both interfaces so I won't cover that here - you can find them by googling "[angular custom form control](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular%20custom%20form%20control)".